# SharePoint 2010 - Added additional WFE to farm but can't access additional site collections

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, ssrs-2008, http-status-code-404, alternate-access-mappings

My SharePoint setup is:

2 Web Front End servers, 1 of those WFE servers is also the application server then there is another server for my SQL database.

[image: SharePoint Setup]

Server 2 which is the WFE and App Server combined is able to access all the site collections. Server 1 however can only access the root collection and is unable to access any other site collections I've created, Business Intelligence Centre for example.

To access the root collection I type in:

`http://test1:100/` and I receive the Standard SharePoint team webpage.

If I alter the address to `http://test2:100/` it opens up the same page without a problem.

When I navigate to `http://test2:100/dept/bic/Pages/Default.aspx` it opens with the BIC without a problem. As soon as I change the text from test2 to test1 then I get a 404 error. From what I've read I need to do some work in the Configure Alternate Access Mappings section under System Settings in Central Admin, however I'm lost at what I need to do in order for Server 1 to see this BIC site.

Here is an example of Server 2 accessing the home page, then the BIC

[image: SharePoint Server 2 Access]

Now here is when I use Server 1 to access the home page, then the BIC

[image: SharePoint Server 1 Access]

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right about the alternate access mappings. Although some of the sites might respond like in your situation, SharePoint will only respond properly with an AAM configured for a given URL.  In your case, when you have more than one web server, you need to use some kind of load balancer.  You can look at using [Windows Load Balancing](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831698.aspx) services or you can work with your network team and use a hardware load balancer.  Once you implement load balancing, you will create a new alternate access mapping with a new DNS name that will effectively point to both servers.